# Qt: 3D Horizontal Bar Chart

Tags: c++, qt, 3d, bar-chart, qt3d

I am trying to draw a 3D horizontal bar chart using [Qt 3D](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.6/qt3d-index.html).I am trying to achieve this by drawing consecutive cuboids having the same x , y and rotation and translating them to different depths.But it seemed that changing the depth only is not working as both x and y are also changing and I can't figure it out.

Update:

I found out that the x and y attributes should also be changed by specific values. I hard-coded it and it works fine but I can't figure out an equation to do this automatic with varying dimensions.

[image]

The code:

```
SceneModifier::SceneModifier(Qt3DCore::QEntity *rootEntity)
    : m_rootEntity(rootEntity)
{

    // Green cuboid
    //Cuboid shape data
    cuboid = new Qt3DExtras::QCuboidMesh();
    cuboid->setXExtent(8);
    cuboid->setYExtent(2);
    cuboid->setZExtent(4);
    // CuboidMesh Transform
    Qt3DCore::QTransform *cuboidTransform = new Qt3DCore::QTransform();
    cuboidTransform->setRotation(QQuaternion::fromAxisAndAngle(QVector3D(0.1f, -0.1f, 0.0f), 45.0f));

    Qt3DExtras::QPhongMaterial *cuboidMaterial = new Qt3DExtras::QPhongMaterial();
    cuboidMaterial->setDiffuse(QColor(QRgb(0x66423)));
    cuboidMaterial->setAmbient(QColor(QRgb(0x35423)));
    //Cuboid
    m_cuboidEntity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity(m_rootEntity);
    m_cuboidEntity->addComponent(cuboid);
    m_cuboidEntity->addComponent(cuboidMaterial);
    m_cuboidEntity->addComponent(cuboidTransform);

    // Red Cuboid shape data
     cuboid2 = new Qt3DExtras::QCuboidMesh();
     cuboid2->setXExtent(8);
     cuboid2->setYExtent(2);
     cuboid2->setZExtent(2);

     // CuboidMesh Transform
     cuboidTransform2 = new Qt3DCore::QTransform();
     cuboidTransform2->setRotation(QQuaternion::fromAxisAndAngle(QVector3D(0.1f, -0.1f, 0.0f), 45.0f));

     /*An equation is needed to calculate the translation values*/
     cuboidTransform2->setTranslation(QVector3D(6*qAsin(45.0/180), 6*qAsin(45.0/180),-2.1f));

     Qt3DExtras::QPhongMaterial *cuboidMaterial2 = new Qt3DExtras::QPhongMaterial();
     cuboidMaterial2->setDiffuse(QColor(QRgb(0xff0000)));

     //Cuboid
     m_cuboidEntity2 = new Qt3DCore::QEntity(m_rootEntity);
     m_cuboidEntity2->addComponent(cuboid2);
     m_cuboidEntity2->addComponent(cuboidMaterial2);
     m_cuboidEntity2->addComponent(cuboidTransform2);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem you are having is that the translation happens *after* the rotation. Probably what you want is instead of setting the transform on each cuboid individually, you set the transform on their parent. So don't rotate either cuboid; just translate them normally as if you are viewing directly from above. But then add a rotation transform to `m_rootEntity`.