# How to apply a Vertical texture to a QT Surface3D?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, data-visualization

I'm using QT Surface3D graph to plot some 2D/3D data.
I need to apply a Texture with some color-scale to my data.
the function surface3dSeries->setTexture works only on horizontal surface,

Is possible to apply a texture on a vertical surface?
(in order to obtain something like a terrain slice)

I need to obtain something like this:
[Surface Chart Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSfeL.png)

Answer (score 0):

- Horizontal or vertical is defined by actual transformation [applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37799092/qt-3d-horizontal-bar-chart) to the 3d object.
- We [apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49887994/qspheremesh-in-qt-3d-how-can-i-correctly-add-a-texture-on-it) the texture to some 3d object with actual position/volume, like [mesh](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt3d-render-mesh.html).
- There different kind of renderer [more universal] or mesh [wants texture] and you want [PlainMesh](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3dextras-qplanemesh.html).

These all topics to be covered and the implementation depends on exact request.

Comment: Hi, thank for your reply. I've edited my question and now you can see a preview of what I need to do.